# why can I say that $(-\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3})^4$ =$(\cos \frac{2\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{3})^4$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Express $\frac{\cos \frac{\pi}{6} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{6}}{  (-\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3})^4}$ in $\cos x + i\sin x$ and $x+yi$

For the denominator, why can I say that $(-\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3})^4$ =$(\cos \frac{2\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{3})^4$ ?

I continued doing the question:

For the denominator, I used demoivre's theorem: $4(\cos \frac{8\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{8\pi}{3})$

That gives me $\frac{\cos \frac{\pi}{6} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{6}}{\cos \frac{8\pi}{3} + i\sin\frac{8\pi}{3}}$

I probably know how to carry on with this, so my main question is

> why can I say that $(-\cos \frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{3})^4$ =$(\cos \frac{2\pi}{3} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{3})^4$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That step most likely came from the facts

$$ \begin{align*}
-\cos x &= \cos(\pi-x) \\
\sin x &= \sin(\pi-x)
\end{align*} $$

This could be used to get from any $\pm(-\cos \theta +i\sin \theta)$ situation into a Euler's equation form.